# Table of contents?

Tags: table-of-contents

I'm fairly new to latex so I would like to know how do I insert a table of contents?
I have four chapters each with subsections so how must I add table of contents?

P.S. I tried using, `\tableofcontents` but its not what I wanted. I have a somewhat table of contents, however my introduction isn't showing and neither is my bibliography(these are not listed as chapters). Only the chapters are showing up in the TOC. But I also want the TOC to say "Chapter 1" instead of "1" as well as include introduction and bibliography.

Edit as suggested:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{report}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents


Introduction

bla bla bla 

\chapter{Generalities on linear representations}



\chapter{Character theory}



\chapter{Fourier transform on finite groups}




\chapter{Future work}



\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Type `\tableofcontents` without spaces.

Comment: That's what I did in the document!

Comment: What's your document class? The intro is an unnumbered chapter?

Comment: Document class is a report. and yes, its an unnumbered chapter same with the bibliography.

Comment: A minimal working example would be good. Please provide the documentclass and the sections or chapters used.

Comment: Then use, just after the command,` \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Introduction}`,  same for the bibliography.

Comment: ok I managed to fix the introduction but why is the bibliography appearing just below the intro? how do I make it that it goes at the bottom?

Comment: and how can rename the "1" to "chapter 1" in the toc?

Comment: There's quite a few problems with this. Firstly, I want the bibliography to appear at the bottom of the toc. Secondly, I would like the introduction to be labelled at page 2 in the toc. Thirdly, I would like it to read "Chapter 1" instead of "1" in the toc. lastly, on page two the top right header should not read "contents".

Comment: I don’t know if its useful to produce more Text in the TOC, than there already is. To push the bibliography to the bottom write the `addcontentsline` to there place where you wnat it to be. The last issue is about the page style and can be changed with packages like fancyhdr.

Comment: Problems 1 and 3 have been fixed now. I still need to fix problems 2 and 4

Comment: @LarsHalbauer I am using fancyhdr package, but I don't know how to fix it. please help as its frustrating

Comment: Which code did you use for headers?

Comment: @Bernard I posted a separate question on this  refer https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/500208/some-problems-with-toc-and-usage-of-fancyhdr-package