# Some problems with toc and usage of fancyhdr package

Tags: table-of-contents, fancyhdr

Firstly, I would like to have my introduction the same as my bibliography(font and location) (Photo 1) the introduction is better seen in photo 2[image]

Secondly, I want to remove the "contents" from the top right on the second page, and label it "introduction" (photo 2)

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{nccmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts, graphicx, verbatim, mathtools,amssymb, amsthm, mathrsfs}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{setspace}% if you must (for double spacing thesis)
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{floatrow}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage[style=numeric,maxbibnames=99,sortcites=true,backend=bibtex]{biblatex}
\setlength\bibitemsep{0.5\baselineskip}
\addbibresource{References.bib}


\begin{document}
\newpage
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[EL]{\nouppercase\leftmark}
\fancyhead[OR]{\nouppercase\rightmark}
\fancyhead[ER,OL]{\thepage}

\tableofcontents

Introduction

bla bla bla 
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Introduction}
\chapter{Generalities on linear representations}

\chapter{Character theory}

\chapter{Fourier transform on finite groups}

\chapter{Future work}

\printbibliography
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Bibliography}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Reports are one side only, there is no twoside option so the `\fancyhead[E/O]` is not useful.

### For question 1

Style it as an unnumberd chapter. `chapter*{Introduction}`

### For question 2

Use `\markboth` to put the text "Introduction" into the left and right marks (Only Right mark techinically needed though). Unnumbered chapters are not automatically put into the Contents.
By forcing the page style to be fancy the header can be made to appear, normally they are `plain` for opening chapter pages

```
\chapter{Introduction}
\thispagestyle{fancy}
```

### Your corrected code is below

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{nccmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts, graphicx, verbatim, mathtools,amssymb, amsthm, mathrsfs}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{setspace}% if you must (for double spacing thesis)
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{floatrow}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage[style=numeric,maxbibnames=99,sortcites=true,backend=bibtex]{biblatex}
\setlength\bibitemsep{0.5\baselineskip}
\addbibresource{References.bib}


\begin{document}
\newpage
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead[R]{\nouppercase\leftmark}
\fancyhead[L]{\thepage}
\fancyfoot{}
\tableofcontents
\markboth{Introduction}{Introduction}
\chapter*{Introduction}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Introduction}
\thispagestyle{fancy}
bla bla bla
\lipsum[1-4]

\chapter{Generalities on linear representations}

\chapter{Character theory}

\chapter{Fourier transform on finite groups}

\chapter{Future work}

\printbibliography
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Bibliography}
\end{document}
```

### Example

[image: Example of unlabelled but in TOC]

Comment: Can you show what the output will be?

Comment: unfortunately, this is not what I want.

Comment: I'll just leave the intro as an unnumbered chapter as you suggested and stick with it

Comment: I've attached the example. If you want to remove the header on the Introduction page, remove `\thispagestyle{fancy}`

Comment: I wanted it, but this code plays up with the rest of the document as in all the headings read "chapter 1 generalities…"

Comment: If you provide a minimal example showing the incorrect headings then perhaps I can see what is resetting the headings. In my MWE with lipsum text in the other chapters the headings are working fine. Otherwise opening another question with the specifics of your packages that cause the heading mark to not work might be more appropriate

Comment: sorry, I was away for the weekend. but i'll add a MWE soon

Comment: in fact, i'll just keep it as it is. thanks for you help :)